# How to set python class attribute to value of another, previously defined class attribute in class definition?

Tags: python, oop, class

I am defining a python class and would like to declare a set of class attributes, then use those attributes in initializing a list that will also be stored as a class attribute.

```
class SampleClass( models.Model ):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Class attributes
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # field names
    FIELD_NAME_ID = "ID"
    FIELD_NAME_USER = "User"

    # Field name list
    FIELD_NAME_LIST = []
    FIELD_NAME_LIST.append( SampleClass.FIELD_NAME_ID ) # = "ID"
    FIELD_NAME_LIST.append( SampleClass.FIELD_NAME_USER ) # = "User"

    # rest of class definition
    # ...

#-- END class SampleClass --#
```

This is similar in Java to defining class variables, then using them to initialize other, subsequently defined class variables.

In this example, I try to reference them using the class name, for example: `SampleClass.FIELD_NAME_ID`

This does not work (it breaks the class definition).

Adding list items like this:

```
FIELD_NAME_LIST.append( "ID" ) # = "ID"
```

works fine.

Is there a way to use one class attribute when initializing another in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class body is executed as a function would, and the local namespace entries become the class attributes. So, during execution of the class body, you can treat the other names as local variables:

```
FIELD_NAME_ID = "ID"
FIELD_NAME_USER = "User"

FIELD_NAME_LIST = [FIELD_NAME_ID, FIELD_NAME_USER]
```

You already discovered this since you called `FIELD_NAME_LIST.append("ID")` successfully.